# How to access certain element in a QObjectList-based model in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

Suppose on C++ side I've created a `QList<QObject *> myObjects` which contains several custom objects derived from `QObject`.

And then expose it to QML by `setContextProperty( "myModel", QVariant::fromValue( myObjects ) );`

The question is, in my QML code, how can I get and use a specific element (by index) in `myModel` (which is a `QList`). For instance, I would like to take a random element from the list and show it?

The example is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-objectlistmodel-example.html, where all elements of the model are shown in a ListView`, while I just want to show one (or several) of them.

Comment: QML transparently support `QList<>` types as described in [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#sequence-type-to-javascript-array) document. So C++ array will be converted to common JavaScript array. See it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: so simple and basic question but this is a necessary question. so +1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an item from the list you can use the `[]` operator:

```
myModel[index]
```

The elements of a `QList` are similar to arrays in javascript since QML is based on the latter.

The following example shows getting the names in random form (it only replaces the code in the example).

**view.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

//![0]

ColumnLayout{
    ListView {
        width: 100; height: 100

        model: myModel
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 25
            width: 100
            color: model.modelData.color
            Text {
                text: name
            }
        }


    }

    Button {
        text: "random"
        onClicked: {
            t.text = myModel[ Math.floor(Math.random()*myModel.length)].name;
        }
    }
    Text{
        id: t
        text: ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

its pretty easy...

to get item number i from the model:

```
myModel[i]
```

and to access its properties/roles:

```
myModel[i].propertyName
```

Comment: Simple and clear answer. also don't forget to register qml type in `main.cpp` file to make it accessible in qml. see documentation.